# Consider the following BNF Grammar

Tags: grammar, expression-trees, bnf

Consider the following BNF grammer (where non-terminals are enclosed in angle-brackets and `<identifier>` matches to any legal Java variable identifier).

```
<exp> ::= <exp> + <term>
      |   <exp> - <term>
      |   <term>
<term> ::= <term> * <factor>
       |   <term> / <factor>
       |   <factor>
<factor> ::= ( <exp> )
         |   <identifier>
```

Produce a derivation three for the following expression:

```
(x - a) * (y + b)
```

Staring with exp:

```
<exp>
```

replace exp with term:

```
<term>
```

replace term with:

```
<term> * <factor>
```

replace term with factor:

```
<factor> * <factor>
```

replace both factors with (exp):

```
( <exp> ) * ( <exp> )
```

replace the first exp with exp - term and the second with exp + term

```
( <exp> - <term> ) * ( <exp> + <term> )
```

replace both exp's with term, and then replace all 4 terms with factors.

```
( <factor> - <factor> ) * ( <factor> + <factor> )
```

replace all factors with identifiers

```
( <identifier> - <identifier> ) * ( <identifier> + <identifier> )
```

Does this suffice?

Comment: You have to start with `<exp>`, don't you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to go one step further - `<factor>` is a nonterminal, and you should reduce it down to `<identifier>`.

Additionally, you should be starting from `<expr>` (and then reducing it to `<term>`) rather than starting from `<term>` directly.